# How to cube on two columns as if they were one?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a following attributes that I am interested on performing aggregations (regular count for example) on attributes:

```
'category', 'sub-category', age, city, education... (around 10 more)
```

I am interested in all possible combinations of the attributes in group by, so using dataframes *cube* function could help me achieve that.

But here is a catch: *sub-category* does not make any sense without *category*, so in order to achieve this I need to combine rollup(category, sub-category) with cube(age, city. education...).

How to do this?

This is what I tried, where *test* is the name of my table:

```scala
val data = sqlContext.sql("select category,'sub-category',age from test group by cube(rollup(category,'sub-category'), age )")
```

and this is the error I get:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'test.`category`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, by sharing example data, code you have tried and expected output.

Comment: @Srdjan Nikitovic: Did  you try window functions, it might help you on this?

Comment: @Shankar I do not see any way how window functions could help me with this...

Comment: @SrdjanNikitovic: The error clearly says, you need to use the selected attributes in group by or you should use agg function, but you are not doing any of this. I am not sure about cube function though.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want is `struct` or `expr` functions to combine two columns as one and use it to `cube` on.

With `struct` it'd be as follows:

```
df.rollup(struct("category", "sub-category") as "(cat,sub)")
```

With `expr` it's as simple as using "pure" SQL, i.e.

```
df.rollup(expr("(category, 'sub-category')") as "(cat,sub)")
```

But I'm just *guessing*...